# Overwriting a register in two different always blocks

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, asic

I am trying to write a verilog code for an image labeling algorithm...The algorithm has several stages in which each is to be written as a separate always block...however, as far as I know, a variable (of type reg) used in one always can NOT be used in another always block (which is true of course because each D-Flip Flop has only one input, i.e. can be assigned by one signal only).

How can I possibly overwrite that reg value in another always block?

Comment: Can you please show your effort? and mention the issue you might then face?

Comment: Also study some small tutorial about FPGA's and HDL so that you can understand how it works. The question is very basic, but not explained well.

Comment: The answer depends on further specification.  You can have two inputs multiplexed based on some condition, or you can choose between two different registers (multiplex the outputs).  There are other signals you may want to consider also: asynchronous set/clear, clock enable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a buffer register between the always blocks. However, there will be an extra cycle of delay between the write from always block 2 (see below) and always block 1. The below code resets counter1 to 0 once counter2 reaches 10. counter1 will be one cycle behind counter2. you can extend this strategy to your own implementation hopefully.

```
reg [31:0] counter1 = 0;
reg [31:0] counter2 = 0;
reg counter2_valid = 0;

always @ (posedge clk) begin // Always block 1
    if (counter2_valid == 1'b1) begin
        counter1 <= counter2;
    end else begin
        counter1 <= counter1 + 1;
    end
end

always @ (posedge clk) begin // Always block 2
    if (counter2 == 10) begin
        counter2_valid <= 1'b1;
        counter2 <= 0;
    end else begin
        counter2_valid <= 1'b0;
        counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
    end
end
```